# Is there an API to help me mimic the notetaking I already do in excel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Here's what I need in terms of functionality:

1. multiple columns
2. the ability to write paragraphs in a cell
3. insert a new row under the one currently in
4. preferably options to format

I don't think a JTable could this and I've heard a lot of complaints about JTable generally. It's my visceral reaction that JTextArea would be a nightmare. Are there any alternatives?

Preferably this could be run on any machine and look the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a completely different answer (Since you aren't getting much and didn't like my other).

JTable should work fine.  It supports 1 & 3 directly.

For 2 & 4 it depends on what control you place into the cell.  If you place a JTextArea into each cell you should be able to add a paragraph and format.

Any more complex text control could be used as well, you can place just about anything into each cell of a table.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to edit/create spreadsheets directly if that's what you're after?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're suggesting I create excel sheets with Apache. If that's the case, you're not answering my question. I explicitly do not want to work with excel

Comment: Ahh, correct.  It sounded like you wre already excel centric but just wanted to automate your spreadsheet-based processes.